# In google sheet how to calcul data from another sheet

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, import, range, google-sheets-formula

In google sheet; I have the following table

| sheet_name | L4 cell data |
| --- | --- |
| October_2021 |  |
| November_2021 |  |

Each name corresponds to a sheet in the same file.

I would like to calculate the value of L4 for each sheet automatically.

Eg : first line is the value of the L4 in the October_2021 sheet.

I tested with hyperlink but it's not good, same with concatenate.

---

**Edit 1 :**

I found this solution, but if something is possible without the url I take :)

*here G10 is my sheet_name column*

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/...", CONCATENATE(G10,"!L4"))
```

Comment: You can use the entire URL, or just the part after the d/: --> [Refer Here](https://www.businessinsider.in/tech/how-to/how-to-use-the-importrange-function-in-google-sheets-to-keep-multiple-spreadsheets-in-sync/articleshow/82225073.cms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### from one sheet to another sheet:

```
={INDIRECT(G10&"!L4"); INDIRECT(G11&"!L4")}
```

### from one spreadsheet to another spreadsheet:

```
={IMPORTRANGE("url_or_id"; G10&"!L4"); IMPORTRANGE("url_or_id"; G11&"!L4")}
```

this is the only way